# Data structure best practice regarding unique id's

Tags: javascript

I have these two data structures that I continually find myself choosing between when pulling data from a database:

```
{
    "1": {"location": "seattle", "color": "red"},
    "2": {"location": "irvine", "color": "blue"},
    "3": {"location": "san diego", "color": "green"}
}

{
    "listings":[
        {"id": "1", "location": "seattle", "color": "red"},
        {"id": "2", "location": "irvine", "color": "blue"},
        {"id": "3", "location": "san diego", "color": "green"}
    ]
}
```

Each seems to have pros and cons...

The object structure is great for quickly accessing a value given an id by saying `obj['3'].color` the problem is when listing all objects you have to loop with a `for(key in obj)` loop which seems to be very slow.

The array structure loops much faster using `for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)` but accessing a value given an id is not easy out of the box.  You have to make a function that loops through the entire array checking the id against a supplied parameter.

Here's a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-for-in-array) of the two solutions.

Which do you think is better and why?

Comment: You have a JavaScript object and array, but no JSON here. If you transfer the data as JSON to the client, fine, but once the data is parsed you are not dealing with JSON any more.

Comment: It's the same thing.  Assume the server returns either an object parsed as JSON or an array parsed as JSON.

Comment: It's not. JSON is a data exchange format, while a JavaScript array or object is a data type in JavaScript. Don't be mislead by the similar syntax. If your problem is to figure out what is the best data structure for your purpose, then it is not related to JSON at all.

Comment: see edit -- regardless, it's the structure I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the answer is: **It depends**. Will you mostly access the objects randomly by their `id`? Then use the object. Will you mostly loop through them in order? Then use an array.

Of course, you can do both, by returning an array and then creating an index on it by `id` value. E.g.,

```
var arr = /*...wherever you get your second example, the array...*/;
var index, len, entry;
arr.index = {};
for (index = 0, len = arr.length; index < len; ++index) {
    entry = arr[index];
    arr.index[entry.id] = entry;
}
```

(I have a function that does this because I find it a useful technique periodically.)

Now you can loop through them with a loop, or randomly access them via `arr.index["some_id"]`. Note that you have to be careful when modifying it (e.g., ensure you do deletions and additions in both places).

Note that there I've used a property on the actual array, called `index` (the name can be whatever you like; I frequently use `index` or `byId` or similar). Some people don't like to use non-index properties on arrays; I have no problem with it, since arrays [are really just objects anyway](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). But you don't have to, you can keep track of the index in its own variable as a peer of `arr`.

Also note that while there may be an *absolute* difference in the speed of iteration using `for..in` on the object vs. `for` on the array, the odds of there being any *real-world impact* on that speed of iteration is very low.

Comment: could you elaborate on "returning an array and then creating an index on it by id value"?